# Exception "Module with the Main dispatcher is missing." in release APK only

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm using Kotlin 1.3 EAP and `kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.0-RC1` in my Android project. My development build succeeds and the app runs fine. However, when I `Generate Signed APK`, the app still builds and runs, but then crashes with

> `java.lang.IllegalStateException`: Module with the `Main` dispatcher is missing. Add dependency providing the `Main` dispatcher, e.g. `'kotlinx-coroutines-android'`

Since the dev build runs fine, clearly there's no omission in the gradle files. I have these settings in place:

Project `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0-rc-190'
    ....
```

Module `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.0-RC1'
```

The same application has been running with many different versions of experimental coroutines over time, this is the first time I have experienced this issue. I suspect some interim problem in the EAP artifacts.

What could I try to make this work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using proguard, add these proguard [rules](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/core/kotlinx-coroutines-core/resources/META-INF/proguard/coroutines.pro).

```
# ServiceLoader support
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatcherFactory {}
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandler {}

# Most of volatile fields are updated with AFU and should not be mangled
-keepclassmembernames class kotlinx.** {
    volatile <fields>;
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/README.md#r8-and-proguard)

Comment: Indeed, so my problem isn't related to upgrading Kotlin, but migrating to `androidx`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Adding the suggested proguard rules should be enough. If you are still facing this issue please be sure that you are not re-signing your .apk after the release build is done. I've faced this issue when re-signing the .apk because the **META-INF** folder was being removed. If this is your case, I would suggest you to generate an unsigned build and sign it afterwards. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

ADD THIS LINE INTO YOUR PROGUARD FILE

-keep class kotlinx.coroutines.android.* {*;}